# apache common email how to get email delivery notification on java console

Tags: apache, email, jakarta-mail

I have been using JavaMailSender but for the purpose of mail delivery notification on my app I looked for Apache Common Email but was not able to
implement this mail delivery status mechanism.

This is my code:

```
  String smtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";

  final String userid =  "xxxx";
  final String password = "xxxx";
  String contentType = "text/html";
  String subject = "an email to a fake address"
  String from = "xxxxx";
  String to = "xxx";//some invalid address
  String body = "Body: an email to a fake address";

  Properties props = new Properties();

  props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
  props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
  props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpServer);
  props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
  props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
  props.put("mail.smtp.from", from);

  Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props,
     new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
           return new PasswordAuthentication(userid, password);
        }
     });

  MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
  message.addFrom(InternetAddress.parse(from));
  message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
  message.setSubject(subject);
  message.setContent(body, contentType);
  message.setHeader("Return-Receipt-To", "XXXXXX");
  message.setHeader("Disposition-Notification-To", "xxxxxxxx");
  SMTPMessage smtpMessage = new SMTPMessage(message);

  smtpMessage.setNotifyOptions(SMTPMessage.NOTIFY_FAILURE|SMTPMessage.NOTIFY_SUCCESS);  

  Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();
  try {
     System.out.println("Sending ....");
     transport.connect(smtpServer, port, userid, password);
     transport.sendMessage(message,
        message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
     System.out.println("Sending done ...");         

  } catch (Exception e) {
     System.err.println("Error Sending: ");
     e.printStackTrace();

  }
  transport.close();
```

By this code I am able to send receipt approval notification but i am not able to see it within my application.

Any how I managed to scan inbox of the mailserver and shown it in my app.

Please Help me.

Comment: Do you want a [Delivery Status Notification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3464.txt)?  You might need to use the JavaMail API directly.

Comment: Yes but I want it to be shown in my application . Please suggest ways

Comment: Which part are you confused about?  First, read all about DSNs so you know how they work and when they won't work.  Then configure JavaMail to request DSNs.   Then read the mailbox where the DSNs will be delivered.  Then extract the data from the DSN.  Then display it in your application.  Simple, right?  :-)

Comment: i have read it but not able to understand and implement. Please help me

Comment: I can't help you because I don't know what part you're confused about.  I'm definitely not going to do all the work for you so you at least need to spend enough time to try something, show us what you did, and ask for help with something specific.

Comment: thanks I will be updating soon to you with sample code get DSN.

Comment: with java mail i have used return-reciept and disposition headers & also an image file for read notification but both of them are not the reliable ones .

Comment: please see the code i have updated as per your guidelines ,by this code I am able to send receipt approval notification but i am notable to see it within my application,I managed to scan inbox of the mailserver and shown it in my app. But I dont think its the right way

Comment: The Disposition-Notification-To header gives an email address where DSN messages will be sent.  Your application needs to monitor the Inbox corresponding to that address for these DSN messages.  It sounds like you're already doing that.  There's no bound on how long it might take for these DSN messages to be returned, and they may never come at all.  Your application needs to be prepared for that.  There is no guaranteed way to determine whether or not a message has been delivered, received, or read.

Comment: Thanks Bill, if you know any other way please let me know so that I can figure it for my understanding  because how these campaigning tools works for tracking mails.